# Distributive lattices -> left regular bands -> Atomistic lower semimodular lattices

Tags: reference-request, lattice-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

Consider the following construction : let $(L,\vee,\wedge)$ be a finite distributive lattice, and let $(\mathrm{Int}(L),\star)$ be the monoid defined on the set of non empty intervals of $L$
$$\mathrm{Int}(L)=\lbrace[a,b]\mid a,b\in L, a\leq b\rbrace$$
with multiplication given by the formula
$$
[a,b]\star[c,d]=[(a\vee c)\wedge b,(a\vee d)\wedge b]
$$
(associativity of this multiplication turns out to be equivalent to distributivity of $L$ or equivalently to the requirement that the composite of projections of the sort $\pi^+_{[a,b]}:L\to L,x\mapsto (a\vee x)\wedge b$ is again a projection).
This monoid turns out to be a left regular band (LRB) which means that for all intervals $I$, $J$ one has $I\star I=I$ and $I\star J\star I=I\star J$. The unit is $L=[0_L,1_L]$.

To any (finite unital) LRB $(B,\cdot)$ one associates its intersection lattice $(\Lambda_B,\cap)$ which is the lattice of all principal left ideals $Bx$ (one has $Bxy=Bx\cap By$ so that $B\to\Lambda_B,x\mapsto Bx$ is a morphism of lattices; details may be found in the paper [Poset topology and homological invariants of algebras arising in algebraic combinatorics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.6680) by S. Margolis, F. Saliola and B. Steinberg.) In the case of the monoid of intervals of a distributive lattice, I'll write $\Lambda_L=\Lambda_{\mathrm{Int}(L)}$.

The right Green order is given by inclusion of intervals. It's possible to characterize the intervals $I$, $J$ that define the same principal left ideal : $\mathrm{Int}(L)I=\mathrm{Int}(L)J$ iff $I$ and $J$ are equivalent under the equivalence relation of perspective (projectivity?), which is the equivalence relation generated by $[a\wedge b,a]\sim[b,a\vee b]$. One proves that $\Lambda_L$ is **atomistic lower-semimodular**. It is easy to see that the $\mathscr{L}$-classes of $\Lambda_L$ (i.e. the sets of intervals that generate the same principal left ideal) form distributive lattices themselves.

> Atomistic **upper**-semimodular lattices are known as [geometric lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_lattice) and are of interest in matroid theory : quoting from Wikipedia "geometric lattices [...] form the lattices of flats of finite [...] matroids".
>
> 1) Do atomistic **lower**-semimodular lattices have any interpretation or relevance?
>
> 2) Also : is this simple construction already known?

I plan to include this family of examples in my thesis, and would like to properly reference them if it already exists somewhere.

Comment: I haven't seen this lrb construction

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thank you for commenting. Have you perchance encountered atomistic lower-semimodular lattices in the litterature? I initially thought they might be related to antimatroids, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Not sure if this can be useful but$$[a,b]\star[c,d]=[a,b]\cap[b\land c,a\lor d]$$

Comment: I don't know the official name for the dual concept to geometric lattice.